# How can the method Dictionary.Add be O(1) amortized?

Tags: c#, dictionary, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am trying to get a better understanding of how hashtables and dictionaries work in C# from a complexity perspective (but I guess the language is not an important factor, that's probably just a theoretical question).

I know that the method `Add` of a `Dictionary` is supposed to be O(1) if `Count` is less than the capacity (which is kind of obvious).

However, let's look at that code:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() { }
    public override int  GetHashCode() {
        return 5; //arbitrary value, purposely a constant
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Dictionary<Foo, int> test = new Dictionary<Foo,int>();
    Foo a = new Foo();
    Foo b = new Foo();

    test .Add(a, 5);
    test .Add(b, 6); //1. no exception raised, even though GetHashCode() returns the same hash

    test .Add(a, 10); //2. exception raised
}
```

I understand than behind the scenes there is a collision of hashes at `1.` and there's probably a separate chaining to handle it.

However, at `2.` the argument exception is raised. That means that internally the Dictionary keeps a track of each key inserted after having determined its hash. That also means that each time we add an entry to our dictionary, it checks if the key has not already been inserted using the `equals` method.

My question is, why is it considered to be O(1) complexity when it seems like it should be O(n) if it checks the already inserted keys?

Comment: You have just discovered why it is important to have a good GetHashCode function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it doesn't have to check all of the keys. It only has to check keys that hash to the same value. And, as you say, a good hash code will minimize the number of hash collisions, so on average it doesn't have to make any key comparisions at all.

Remember, the rules for `GetHashCode` say that if `a.HashCode <> b.HashCode`, then `a <> b`. But if `a.HashCode == b.GetHashCode`, `a` *might be equal to* `b`.

Also, you say:

> Iknow that the method Add of a Dictionary is supposed to be O(1) if Count is less than the capacity (which is kind of obvious).

That's not entirely true. That's the *ideal*, assuming a perfect hash function that will give a unique number for every key. But the perfect hash function doesn't exist, in the general case, so typically you'll see O(1) (or very close to it) performance until Count exceeds some fairly large percentage of the capacity: say 85% or 90%.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple and difficult. 
Simple part: It is because (you can check it by yourself)

```
a.Equals(b) == false
```

If you want exception when adding "b" just implement also Equals method.

No difficult part:
Default object implementation of Equals call RuntimeHelpers.Equals. Source of RuntimeHelpers is [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers@cs/1305376/RuntimeHelpers@cs). Unfortunately the method is extern:

```
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    public new static extern bool Equals(Object o1, Object o2);
```

What is excatly implementation of this method, I do not know, but I think it base on pointers (so adresses in memory).